# List rows only if they are within a description of ON and OFF

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table with the following fields, I need a view/query where it will  list for every account in the table first the row that start with 
Descr = ON TEST (if it exists) "THRU" Descr= OFF TEST.

It needs to list all the rows in between, but ignore all others.

Thanks in advance.

```
account      date                descr
1234      10/05/15 17:45:23      MISC
1234      10/05/15 17:45:24      ON TEST
1234      10/05/15 17:51:32      DOOR
1234      10/05/15 17:52:52      CLOSE
1234      10/05/15 17:55:08      OPEN
1234      10/05/15 17:56:56      CLOSE
1234      10/05/15 18:08:16      OPEN
1234      10/05/15 18:10:28      CLOSE
1234      10/05/15 18:10:32      CLOSE
1234      10/05/15 18:15:02      OFF TEST
1234      10/05/15 19:10:32      CLOSE
```

Desired result::

```
1234      10/05/15 17:45:24      ON TEST
1234      10/05/15 17:51:32      DOOR
1234      10/05/15 17:52:52      CLOSE
1234      10/05/15 17:55:08      OPEN
1234      10/05/15 17:56:56      CLOSE
1234      10/05/15 18:08:16      OPEN
1234      10/05/15 18:10:28      CLOSE
1234      10/05/15 18:10:32      CLOSE
1234      10/05/15 18:15:02      OFF TEST
```

Comment: This question does not show any research effort.

Comment: Your table seem to go in datetime ascending order. FInd the time of ON row, then time of OFF row and select everything between those times

Comment: Do a double self join, one for start and one for end.

Comment: Is it possible to have multiple ON/OFF groups for the same account?

Comment: dnoeth yes it is possible to have multiple ON/OFF groups on same account

Comment: which ON/OFF group do you need when there are more than 1 of those groups?

Comment: Need to list all on/off groups, for each account

Answer (score 2):

Getting the on/off dates in the general case is a bit tricky.  This follows your rules and should get the dates.

```
select t.account, ton.on_date,
       min(case when t.date >= ton.on_date) as off_date
from t join
     (select account, min(date) as on_date
      from t
      where t.descr = 'ON TEST'
      group by account
     ) ton
     on t.account = ton.account
where t.descr = 'OFF TEST'
group by t.account, ton.on_date;
```

To get the original rows:

```
with onoff as (
      select t.account, ton.on_date,
             min(case when t.date >= ton.on_date) as off_date
      from t join
           (select account, min(date) as on_date
            from t
            where t.descr = 'ON TEST'
            group by account
           ) ton
           on t.account = ton.account
      where t.descr = 'OFF TEST'
      group by t.account, ton.on_date
     )
select t.*
from t join
     onoff
     on t.account = onoff.account
where t.date between onoff.on_date and onoff.off_date;
```

The problem is much simpler if you assume that there are no "off"s before the first "on".  For instance:

```
      select t.*
      from t join
           (select account,
                   min(case when t.descr = 'ON TEST' then date end) as on_date,
                   min(case when t.descr = 'OFF TEST' then date end) as off_date
            from t
            group by account
           ) onoff
           on t.account = ton.account
       where t.date between onoff.on_date and onoff.off_date;
```

Answer (score 1):

Double self join, one for start and and for stop:

```
select t.account, t.date, t.descr
from tablename t
join tablename tstart on t.account = tstart.account
                     and tstart.descr = 'ON TEST'
join tablename tstop  on t.account = tstop.account
                     and tstop.descr = 'OFF TEST'
where t.date between tstart.date and tstop.date
```

Alternatively, double `EXISTS`:

```
select t.account, t.date, t.descr
from tablename t
where exists (select 1 from tablename tstart
              where t.account = tstart.account
                and tstart.descr = 'ON TEST'
                and t.date >= tstart.date)
  and exists (select 1 from tablename tstop
              where t.account = tstop.account
                and tstop.descr = 'ON TEST'
                and t.date <= tstop.date)
```

Comment: Thanks
it lists items past the OFF TEST, only want to see rows within the ON/OFF range.

66406451 09/09/15 08:32:18 ON TEST
66406451 09/09/15 08:32:22 
66406451 09/09/15 08:34:54 CLO
66406451 09/09/15 08:35:36 CLO
66406451 09/09/15 08:35:38 RES
66406451 09/09/15 08:36:40 OPEN
66406451 09/09/15 08:36:42 CANCEL
66406451 09/09/15 08:38:30 RE
66406451 09/09/15 08:38:56 RE
66406451 09/09/15 08:41:10 
66406451 09/09/15 08:42:02 OFF TEST
**66406451 09/09/15 09:15:50 OPEN
66406451 09/09/15 09:19:22 CLOSE
66406451 09/09/15 10:22:18 
66406451 09/09/15 15:17:40**

Answer (score 0):

Select all rows between ON TEST date and OFF TEST date.

```
select *
from table_name
where date >= (select date from table_name where descr = 'ON TEST')
and date <= (select date from table_name where descr = 'OFF TEST')
order by date asc
```

Comment: But easy to fix by making the subquery correlated, just add a where clause in the two subqueries.

Answer (score 0):

You need to compare the most recent timestamp for 'ON TEST' and 'OFF TEST' and check if 'ON' is greater than 'OFF':

```
SELECT *
FROM
 ( SELECT t.*,
      (SELECT MAX(date) -- most recent 'ON TEST'
       FROM tab AS t2
       WHERE t2.account = t.account
         AND t2.date <= t.date
         AND t2.descr = 'ON TEST') AS last_on,
      (SELECT MAX(date) -- most recent 'OFF TEST'
       FROM tab AS t2
       WHERE t2.account = t.account
         AND t2.date <  t.date
         AND t2.descr = 'OFF TEST') AS last_off
   FROM tab AS t
 ) AS dt
WHERE last_on >= COALESCE(last_off, last_on) -- 'ON' > 'OFF' or no previous 'OFF'
```

In SQL Server 2012 this would be easier using `OVER`, e.g.

```
MAX(CASE WHEN descr = 'ON TEST' THEN date END)
OVER (PARTITION BY account
      ORDER BY date
      ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS last_on
```